# Using ASP.NET Role Authorisation with IdentityServer3 implicit flow

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-core, identityserver3

My single page application uses OidcTokenManager to connect to an IdentityServer3 STS using implicit flow. The client presents the IDS3 access token to a ASP.NET Core (WebApi) web service as a Bearer Token; the web service application is configured to use IDS3 middleware and restricts access to its methods using an Authorize attribute.

**SPA client configuration:**

```js
function configureTokenManager() {
    console.log("configureTokenManager()");
    var config = {
        authority: $config.authority,
        client_id: "BNRegistry",
        redirect_uri: $config.webRoot + "/#/authorised/",  
        post_logout_redirect_uri: $config.webRoot + "/#/",

        response_type: "id_token token",
        scope: "openid profile email BNApi",

        silent_redirect_uri: $config.webRoot + "/#/renew/",
        silent_renew: true,

        filter_protocol_claims: false
    };
    return new OidcTokenManager(config);
};
```

**Scope configuration in STS:**

```
new Scope
    {
        Name = "BNApi",
        DisplayName = "BN Api",
        Enabled = true,
        Type = ScopeType.Resource,
        Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>
        {
            new ScopeClaim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Name),
            new ScopeClaim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Role)
        }
    }
```

**WebApi configuration:**

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = Configuration["Authority"],
        RequiredScopes = new[] {"BNApi"},
        NameClaimType = IdentityModel.JwtClaimTypes.Name,                
        RoleClaimType = IdentityModel.JwtClaimTypes.Role
    });
```

**WebApi method:**

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    ...
}
```

This works as expected, rejecting an unauthenticated user with a 401. If I examine the claims for the user in the api controller method, (eg. `User.Claims.ToList()`), it contains entries for any roles to which the user has been assigned.

However, if I examine the `User.Identity.Name` property it is always null, and if I query `User.IsInRole("Administrator")` it is always false, even when the user is assigned to that role. Further, if I add a role name to the `Authorize` attribute (`[Authorize(Role="Administrator")]`), users are rejected with a 401 whether or not they belong to the stated role.

How can I get IdentityServer3 to play nicely with ASP.NET Role authorisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried resetting the `InboundClaimTypeMap`?

From the IdentityServer3 documentation page [here](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html):

> When you inspect the claims on the about page, you will notice two
>   things: some claims have odd long type names and there are more claims
>   than you probably need in your application.
>
> The long claim names come from Microsoft’s JWT handler trying to map
>   some claim types to .NET's ClaimTypes class types.

Unfortunately this mapping ends up breaking the specific claim names you have defined as `name` and `role`, because their names get transformed and no longer map to what you were expecting. This results in the `[Authorize(Roles = "")]` and `User.IsInRole("")` not working as expected.

In your API `Startup.cs` you should add the following:

```cs
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions()
{
    ...
});
```

---

**EDIT:** The below information was incorrect!. As pointed out by @Paul Taylor "the `AlwaysInclude` property ensures that the relevant claim is always present in an identity token (which is used with the client, not the API). This is a resource scope so the property has no effect.". Thanks for helping me understand a little more about how IdentityServer works :-)

<strike>For the `Name` and `Role` claims to be included when accessing the API, you need to specifically mark them as `alwaysInclude` in your `ScopeClaim` list.</strike>

```cs
new Scope
    {
        Name = "BNApi",
        DisplayName = "BN Api",
        Enabled = true,
        Type = ScopeType.Resource,
        Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>
        {
            new ScopeClaim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Name, true), //<-- Add true here
            new ScopeClaim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Role, true) // and here!
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Jamie Dunstan, however, the AlwaysInclude property ensures that the relevant claim is always present in an identity token (which is used with the client, not the API). This is a resource scope so the property has no effect.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I had mine configured in this way and assumed it was the solution. Have you tried resetting the `InboundClaimTypeMap`? i.e. Add `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();` Right before `app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(...` in your API `Startup.cs`?

Comment: Thanks! That enabled the IsInRole("Administrator") and [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")] functionality. The User.Identity.Name property is still blank unfortunately. Any ideas? Do you have that working in your app?

Comment: In any case, if you update your post to add that and flag the misleading bit, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @PaulTaylor - Thanks for your help! I'm glad your role functionality is now working. TEAM WORK!!!! :-)

Comment: @PaulTaylor - My `User.Identity.Name` does work yes. I am assuming that you have a claim called "name"? If so, how do you add this claim?

Comment: @JamieDunstanMar, I didn't and that was the problem. Many thanks.